# Fahrenheit and Celsius conversion table

Tags: c++

I am in week 3 of coding in C++ and have received a practice problem that is shown below.

Write a program that will print a table of fahrenheit and celsius temperatures from 0 - 212 fahrenheit inside a for loop.  Use column headings of Fahrenheit and Celsius, field widths to right align both columns (right align numbers so ones column, tens column, etc lines up, but center the numbers under the column headings) and 3 decimal places along with a plus or minus sign for celsius, but integers and no plus or minus sign for fahrenheit, and add a dot leader between temperatures (before the Celsius temperature but only spaces before the Fahrenheit temperature).

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int fah;
    float cel;
    cout << "Fahrenheit" << setw(17) << "Celsius" << endl;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    for (fah = 0; fah <= 212; fah++)

    {
        cel = (fah - 32) * (5.0 / 9);

        cout << right << setw(10) << noshowpos << fah
             << setw(17) << setprecision(3)
             << showpos << cel << setfill('.') << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having here is that I only want a dot leader after fahrenheit and before celsius. Not before fahrenheit. Could someone show me how to go about doing so?

p.s. We are using void main for the time being and I am aware that it is bad practice.

Comment: What is the actual output you get (don't need the full table) and what is the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by dot leader? An example of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: _"p.s. We are using void main for the time being and I am aware that it is bad practice."_ It's not _bad practice_ but plain wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver - It sounds like each line should be of the form `Fahrenheit.............Celsius`, with leading spaces.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Your indentation is atrocious. Why?

Comment: It's a work in progress @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Use proper indentation from the start! You'll thank me later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int fah;
  float cel;
  cout << "Fahrenheit" << setw(17) << "Celsius" << endl;
  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  for (fah = 0; fah <= 5; fah++)

  {
    cel = (fah - 32) * (5.0 / 9);

    cout << right << setfill(' ') << setw(10) << noshowpos << fah
         << setfill('.') << setw(17) << setprecision(3)
         << showpos << cel  << endl;
  }
}
```

`setfill` manipulator should come before `setw`. It will use whatever is given as `setfill`'s argument to fill the specified width.